# Applying Conditional Symbology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, definition-query

I'm in charge of a database that contains property information.  I would like to symbolize parcels of land that we have a 'written agreement' with the owner differently than parcels that we do not have written agreements with.

My solution was to create a calculated field (1 or 0) based on if there was any data in the "Agreements" field.

> I'm looking for a more dynamic solution (not having to re-run the
>   field calculation) so that when an agreement is entered into the db,
>   the symbology automatically changes.

This is important because our field staff take the db out into the field on hand-held devices; they need to know which **properties they are allowed to access (green)** vs. which **properties they cannot access (red).**

Comment: you can split parcel layer in two with agreement and without based on definition query and render them with different symbols

Comment: Thats basically the same solution that I had originally, you'd have to continually update that split layer -- it's not dynamic.

Comment: Why it is not dynamic? The datasources of two layers should point to the same feature class/shapefile. So when you modify agreement field in this shapefile/feature class results of definition query change.

Comment: definition does not require flag field. So 1st layer where clause: agreements is not null, where clause of 2nd: agreements is null

Comment: You're so right, my mistake! I was thinking a data export based on a query.  Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @megadrofan When I apply an SQL statment 'Agreement' IS NULL, all of the records in the table disapear. Any thoughts?

Comment: If agreement is empty what displays in the field null or empty? If it is not displaying <Null>  then query should be modified to  'Agreement'=''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split parcel layer in two with agreement and without based on definition query and render them with different symbols.The datasources of two layers should point to the same feature class/shapefile. So when you modify agreement field in this shapefile/feature class results of definition query change.So 1st layer where clause: agreements is not null, where clause of 2nd: agreements is null.

Comment: I just replaced the null statements with empty strings and it seems to work just fine -- Thanks again.  Ex "Agreement" = '' ; "Agreement" <> ''

Comment: It is normal, query sometimes differ, it depends on underlying storage type shapefile/File GDB/Personal GDB/Enterprise DB

Answer (score 1):

If your field calculation/feature selection can be modeled (using ModelBuilder) you could just export out the model to a python script and run the script using Windows [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task).

Comment: Thanks,I'd considered that with a python script, I was just wondering if there was a more instant gratification method as opposed to daily updates.